# Why is IO::Socket::Socks unreliable when creating a proxy chain?

Tags: perl, sockets, proxy

I want to use this module to create a connection using multiple SOCKS proxies, but the module I am using is very unreliable and slow compared to using an external solution such as proxychains. After successfully connecting through the chain of proxies, the while loop begins sending the data through the proxy chain. However, the program crashes with the error: "Out of memory". Does anyone have advice on how to fix the code? Any help would be appreciated.

```
while ($sock) {

$sock->syswrite (
"GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n"
);

}
```

When I look at the Wireshark capture, the initial request is sent without any problems but following requests have duplicate http requests in each packet. See: [Wireshark capture](http://prntscr.com/aue3vu)

Edit: I tried using IO::Async, but the requests aren't sent.

```
my $loop = IO::Async::Loop->new;
my $handle = IO::Async::Handle->new(
write_handle => $sock, 
on_write_ready  => sub {

my $request = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n"
print $sock $request;

    }
);

$loop->add( $handle );
$loop->loop_forever;
```

Edit: I was able to fix the script by establishing a new chain for each request I send. Is it possible to send a CONNECT request through the socks chain to establish a new connection each time I send a http request?

Comment: This is a mostly undocumented and badly formatted code dump. And it is incomplete so that it is impossible to use  it to reproduce your problem. If you expect help I would recommend to fix this. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve )on how to do it better.